# How to override a native class method in ES6?

Tags: ecmascript-6, es6-class

I'm trying to extend the `File` class and override `stream()`:

```js
class MyFile extends File {
    constructor (name, options) {
        super(name, options)
        this.customField = options.customField
    }

    stream () {
        return new ReadableStream({
            async start(controller) {
                /* implementation here */
            },
            async pull(controller) {
                /* implementation here */
            },
            async cancel() {
                /* implementation here */
            }
        })
    }

    async text () {
        // implementation here
    }

    async arrayBuffer () {
        // implementation here
    }

/* Attempt 2
    get [Symbol.toStringTag] () {
        return 'Blob'
    }
    
    static [Symbol.hasInstance] (object) {
        return true
    }
*/
}
```

When using `FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer()` or `FileReader.readAsText()` with `MyFile`, it doesn't call into any of my methods and instead just return an empty buffer/text. I then tried to remove `extends File` and added the code in `Attempt 2` but now an error is thrown: `Argument 1 ('blob') to FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer must be an instance of Blob`.

Comment: From the code you show, it is impossible to tell. Also, I don't see a call to `stream()`.

Comment: "*I'm trying to extend the `File` class and override `stream()`*" - why? What are you trying to do? What is your stream supposed to do differently?

Comment: @Bergi I’m writing an Safari extension that implements the File System APIs and the specification says that I’m supposed to return a `File`. I don’t get to control what the website does with this `File` object.

Comment: @osy Ok, but what files does your extension use and how does it generate them? Can't you just construct a new file object that has the expected contents?

Comment: @Bergi So iOS does not support File System API at all, my extension acts as a bridge between native file reading APIs and JS APIs. Yes, I can read the entire thing and return a blob, but what if the use chooses a 4GB file? One of the big advantages of the File System APIs is that you can do partial reads with the streaming APIs.

Comment: @osy What "*native file reading api*" are you using? If this is not a JS-only extension, you can probably either mod `FileReader` to do what you want, or just create a normal `File` object (that is lazily read by a file reader) in the same way that e.g. an `<input>` element produces it. (Or does that read the file from disk when you select it? I don't know). Or even create a native implementation of `File`, not an ES6 `class`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. A `FileReader` [directly calls](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#readOperation) into the [internal *getStream* method](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#blob-get-stream) of a `Blob`, it does not call `.stream()` on the received object.

I doubt `File` is intended to be subclassed. Use [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), and don't use a `FileReader` at all to read your custom files.

Comment: My understanding of that spec is the “get stream” is “Blob.stream()” which I’m overriding. I believe if everything here is implemented as pure JS, what I would be doing would work. But it seems like one native code calling into another native code is allowed to take “shortcuts” and not think about inheritance. I’m not familiar enough with JS to know if that’s indeed true.

Comment: No, the Blob `stream` method uses the same "*get stream*" algorithm as does the `FileReader`. Yes, the native code does take the shortcut, it does not call the `blob.stream()` JS method - that's what the spec says. I think the class is not designed to be subclassed from. You can [open an issue](https://github.com/w3c/FileAPI/issues/) if you'd like to get an authoritative insight :-)

Comment: Okay, I went ahead and referenced the WebKit sources and it calls the Blob C++ object directly (no going through JSC). That's unfortunate but I can make do with replacing FileReader as well.